# Excel changes the position of comma

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I have this values:

37.9355690659488

and when I paste it in excel, It changes to this value:

379.355.690.659.488

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

It seems an issue with the locale.
It is taking the number you pasted as an integer.

Try settings ([official documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-character-used-to-separate-thousands-or-decimals-c093b545-71cb-4903-b205-aebb9837bd1e)), and please post feedback

1. Click File > Options.
2. On the Advanced tab, under Editing options, clear the Use system
   separators check box.
3. Type new separators in the Decimal separator and Thousands separator boxes.

**Tip**: When you want to use the system separators again, select the Use system separators check box.

**Note**: For a permanent solution, you must change the regional settings in Control Panel.

Comment: "Note: For a permanent solution, you must change the regional settings in Control Panel." - Might also just be able to put `'` at the start to force it to a string.

Comment: The user may not want a string, but just number formatting.

Comment: Agreed, but they may. It's worth noting as a viable workaround.

Comment: I changed the settings and I could paste the value correctly but then I can't plot the value and the chart is empty. Do you have and ideas?

Comment: @Maryammirzakhani  - Sounds like a different problem altogether.

Comment: @Maryammirzakhani - I agree with Ramhound. At any rate, you are welcome to edit the question and post a detailed description of the issue (your description is very brief and possibly insufficient). Images always help.